# Suddenly cannot find a factor after I add a label to my ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a plot for my data using ggplot. I would like to add labels to each bar that take the total of a few of the size categories and divide them by that bar's total value to show what percentage they make up.

The plot works fine without the labels, but when I add them, I get an error message concerning one of the factors making up the plot. I'm not sure how that factor is related to the labels, however.

Here is the head of my data:

```
head(Russets)
       Variety Rate Hollow Double Knob     AllCWT.AC ValueCWT.AC TuberSize
1  Burbank 2019    1     67     42  351 AVGCWT.AC.0.4    224.9234    0-4 oz
2  Burbank 2019    2     65     43  391 AVGCWT.AC.0.4    226.9199    0-4 oz
3  Burbank 2019    3     64     42  362 AVGCWT.AC.0.4    226.9676    0-4 oz
4  Burbank 2019    4     63     43  348 AVGCWT.AC.0.4    237.4483    0-4 oz
5  Burbank 2019    5     67     48  357 AVGCWT.AC.0.4    227.8079    0-4 oz
6 Norkotah 2019    1     73     56  371 AVGCWT.AC.0.4    168.3245    0-4 oz
```

Here is the code I've used to make the percentages:

```
everythingRus = Russets %>% 
 filter(!(TuberSize == "Culls")) %>%
 group_by(Variety,Rate) %>%
 summarize(total = sum(ValueCWT.AC))

mrkRus = Russets %>% 
 filter(TuberSize == "6-10 oz" | TuberSize == "10-13 oz" |TuberSize == "13+ oz") %>%
 group_by(Variety,Rate) %>%
 summarize(mrktotal = sum(ValueCWT.AC))

mrk_evyRus = everythingRus %>% left_join(mrkRus) %>%
 mutate(per = paste0((round(mrktotal/total,2))*100,"%"))


perMrkRus <- data.frame(percentRus = mrk_evyRus$per, y = rep(100,times = 15), 
                    trt = rep(c(1,2,3,4, 5),times = 3))
```

And here is the basic ggplot:

```
RussetPlot <-ggplot(data=Russets,aes(x=Rate,y=ValueCWT.AC,group=interaction(TuberSize,Variety),fill=(TuberSize))) +
  geom_col(position = "stack",inherit.aes = TRUE) +
  facet_wrap(~Variety,nrow=2) +
  geom_label(data = perMrkRus, aes(x= trt,y=y,label = percentRus))
```

When I run it without the last line of code, it works fine. However, when I add that line in, I get the following error:

> Error in interaction(TuberSize, Variety) : object 'TuberSize' not found

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here? I'm not sure how this error relates to adding the labels. Please let me know if there's any more information that I can provide. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, that solved the problem! If you don't mind, could you explain how that addition solved the issue? I'd like to know how that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your last line, try:

```
geom_label(data = perMrkRus, aes(x= trt,y=y,label = percentRus), inherit.aes=F)
```

The issue is that when you define the data and aethetics for your plot, `ggplot` assumes (often rightly) that you are going to use the same data and the same plotting aesthetics (choice of x and y data, grouping, etc.) all the way through the plotting commands. In your case, `ggplot` is still trying to reference the grouping aesthetic - which you haven't redefined - even though `TuberSize` doesn't exist in the data you've given it in that last line. By calling `inherit.aes=F`, you're explicitly telling ggplot to forget the aesthetics you used in earlier parts of the call.